# Заполнение массива объектов в таблицу

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
let names = [
  {
    name: 'Name 1',
    language: 'ru',
  },
  {
    name: 'Name 2',
    language: 'en',
  }
];
let table = document.querySelector('.tbody');
    
valTableName();
function valTableName(){
  names.forEach(element => {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    table.append(tr);

    let td = document.createElement('td');
    tr.append(td);
    td.append(element);
  });
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody class="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Создавать TR по длине массива, то есть в данном примере 2 tr, а внутри tr 2 td. Чтобы в первом TD было значение name, а во втором TD значение language и так далее по всем TR.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> Name 1 </td>
    <td> RU </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Name 2 </td>
    <td> EN </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

У меня уже голова кругом, я столько всего перепробовал, может я неправильно создал массив с объектами. Покажите правильную дорогу!

Comment: `table.innerHTML = names.map( obj => '<tr><td>' + obj.name + '</td><td>' + obj.language + '</td></tr>' ).join("");` - можно еще так, сразу вставить)

Comment: Optimus Вы не успели мне помочь)) Хотя всегда Вы первый на ответе. Хотя Вы же тут не ночуете)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

коли у вас в метках jquery, то можно примерно так

```js
let names = [
  {
    name: 'Name 1',
    language: 'ru',
  },
  {
    name: 'Name 2',
    language: 'en',
  }
];

names.forEach(function(obj){
   const s = `<tr><td>${obj.name}</td><td>${obj.language}</td></tr>`;
   $(s).appendTo(".tbody");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tbody class="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, то что нужно!)
Реально, сидел очень долго, вроде получалось, но вообще не то, я видимо не по тому пути шёл.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let names = [
  {
    name: 'Name 1',
    language: 'ru',
  },
  {
    name: 'Name 2',
    language: 'en',
  }
];
let table = document.querySelector('.tbody');
    
valTableName();
function valTableName(){
  names.forEach(element => {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    table.append(tr);
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td')).append(element.name);
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td')).append(element.language);
  });
}
```

```css
td{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody class="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо и Вам, я уже молился Богу, чтобы найти ответ.
Но Боги обитают на stackoverflow !)

Answer (score 0):

С использованием деструктуризации и стандартных свойств DOM:

```js
let names = [
  { name: 'Name 1', language: 'ru' },
  { name: 'Name 2', language: 'en' }
];
let table = document.querySelector('.tbody');
valTableName(table, names);

function valTableName(tbody, data) {
  for (const { name, language } of data) {
    const tr = tbody.insertRow(); 
    tr.insertCell().textContent = name; 
    tr.insertCell().textContent = language; 
  }
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { padding: 0.5em 1em; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

При большем количестве свойств в объектах из массива, разумнее будет использование вспомогательного массива ключей (имен свойств) - для сохранения порядка следования ячеек, без дублирования кода. Например:

```
keys.forEach(k => tr.insertCell().textContent = entry[k]);
```

Это имеет смысл просто потому, что стандарт не обязывает браузеры сохранять порядок объявления свойств объекта (хоть современные браузеры и делают это, возможны случаи когда вывод например через цикл по `Object.values` окажется "перемешанным").